# Overloading error message stemming from wrong GET-request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a view that looks like this:

```
class Foo(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format = None):
       #...
```

So my question is very simple: how do I override the error message that is returned in case of POST-request?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to override the `.post()` method. Based on your implementation in your view, where you want to return an error, return Django Rest Framework's [`Response`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#response) instead of Django's `HttpResponse`.

Your final view could look something like:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.status import HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST


class Foo(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            # code that raises an error
        except:
            error_msg = {
                'error': 'Your error message here.'
            }
            return Response(
                data=error_msg, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )
```

Comment: Perhaps I failed to explain the question clearly. My class-based view does not have ANY post-method. And I want to override Django's default error-message when someone tries to call a post-method - FOR A VIEW WITH ONLY GET-request

Comment: To override the post error message, you'll have to implement the post method